# Group Multiple pytest cases for the same function

Tags: python, pytest

How to group multiple pytests for the same function?

The naming convention `test_<function name>_case_<test description>` would work. But this looks kind of tedious when there are lots of function and lots of test cases for each function.

Parameterization won't help in this case because different test case perform different check for the function.

Current method (naming convention):

```
import pytest

class apple():
    def __init__(*args):
       ...

def eat(food):
    ...

def test_apple_case_color_is_red():
    """test if color is red"""
    assert apple().color == "red"

def test_apple_case_edible():
    """test if apple is edible"""
    assert eat(apple)
```

Can't group the two tests together by parametrization because the two tests do different checks.

unittest can group the test cases:

```
import unittest

class TestApple(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_color():
        """check if color is red"""
        assert apple().color == "red"
    def test_edible():
        """check if edible"""
        assert eat(apple)
```

Comment: I am unclear what you are asking.  You are quite free to put as many asserts as you desire into one `test_...` function.  What are you trying to do?  Keep in mind that the **ONLY** point of the function naming to make it easier to interpret the test report.

Comment: Suppose I am testing an apple. One test would test if it is red. Another one would test if it is edible. If the edible test fails, I know what is wrong with the apple. On the other hand, if I put all asserts into the same test, then it takes a while to read the output, figure out which assert fail, and what does that means.

Comment: This naming convention is a bit tedious because it repeats `thing` and `case` for every test of `thing`. If we can group all tests for `thing` together, then at least I don't have to read/type `thing` for so many times.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but so what?  In the end what are unit tests for?  They are for finding problems.  OK, the test fails.  Now what?  Well, you start to debug.  The failing assert is shown in the report.  The test case name does not tell the whole story, how does this matter?

Comment: I'd go for parametrization of the tests https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html

Comment: You could parametrize inputs along with the expected values, no?

Comment: Also, you don't need to split each assert in its own test function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Seems a bit silly given the simplicity of your example but it's the gist of it.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
    ("0", 0),
    ("1", 1),
    ("10", 10),
])
def test_thing_with_input(input, expected):
    assert len(thing(4,input)) == expected

def test_thing_empty():
    assert thing(4,0) == []
```

Given the update, you can also make a class containing tests in pytest

```
class TestThing:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("input,expected", [
        ("0", 0),
        ("1", 1),
        ("10", 10),
    ])
    def test_with_input(self, input, expected):
        assert len(thing(4,input)) == expected

    def test_empty(self):
        assert thing(4,0) == []
```

Comment: @Rzu updated the answer given your edit in the question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your question there are two things here:

- being able to define several test datasets ('cases') on one hand
- being able to define several test functions ('logic') on the other hand

And obviously blend the two to generate your tests. This is often the case for data science tests where you have many test datasets, sometimes more than test cases.

You can use [pytest-cases](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/) for that (I'm the author by the way):

```
from pytest_cases import CaseData, THIS_MODULE, CaseDataGetter, cases_data

# --------- test cases ----------
def case_red_apple() -> CaseData:
    """ Returns a red apple """
    return apple('red'), None, None

def case_green_apple() -> CaseData:
    """ Returns a green apple """
    return apple('green'), None, None

# ------- test functions
@cases_data(module=THIS_MODULE)
def test_apple_color(case_data: CaseDataGetter):
    """ Grabs an apple and check that its color is ok """
    apple = case_data.get()
    assert apple.color in {'red', 'green'}

@cases_data(module=THIS_MODULE)
def test_apple_else(case_data: CaseDataGetter):
    """ Grabs an apple and asserts something else """
    apple = case_data.get()
    # assert something else...
```

However from your question I also sense that you wish to **chain** two tests on the same instance: you wish to see, for each test data (for each apple), a sequence of test steps executed on it (color test, then edibility test). This is also feasible, as explained [here](https://smarie.github.io/python-pytest-cases/usage/advanced/#test-suites-several-steps-on-each-case).